# Centering text in custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, android-widget

i have a little problem with UI component.

I have created my own widget that contains elevatedButton - it is supposed to be used for login instances.

The problem is that i can not center properly my text widget.

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
                child: Image.asset(
                  imagepath,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

https://imgur.com/a/NF82cW9 - here is example of my problem.

The beggining of Text widget is not on the same width - and it should be.

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried centering the text widget?
or you should try to wrap text widget only with expanded widget instead of pading widget that will solve your problem probably.

```
           Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Expanded(
              child:  Text(
                text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: ya, this was my first thought when i tried to solve this case. Unfortunately non of my trials were successful. I tried flexible widget instead of expanded, delete padding, add sizedbox with width - but now there's problem with responsive design  - also fractionedsiezdbox etc .. nothing worked propely ;v

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Expanded` with `Flexible`

If doesn't work wrap text widget with `Center`

Comment: I think i tried this also and it still didnt work. I mean when i am using Center() widget it is obviously centered, but texts are different lengths and it is causing problem i have encountered yet that the beggining is not on the same level. I guess i will have to just put sizedbox(width) between img asset and text and use screenUtil lib

Comment: wait so you want text center based on width of button ignoring image asset, you think image asset is shifting its center, right? If that's the case use `stack` widget, it will overlap image on top of text widget.